# A visual crack the code puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

[image]

Just have this now what are all these acronyms refer to and what is the code ?

Comment: What is the source of this puzzle?

Comment: some treasure hunt

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tOBUeCNt76r-HbjunRSd_skAas9Zo8YH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This question appears to be from an ongoing competition, so it has been locked until the competition is over.